# How do I get my flatList to render an Array objects with nested objects as attributes from useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm, react-hooks

I am wanting to do the following:
1) retrieve data from an API
2) store it in local Realm instance
3) pull array of objects stored in realm and assign data to Data hook
4) display in flatlist

Note that the object contains 2 objects as attributes.

Here is my JS code:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);

 const writeData = response => { //data contains the response 
Realm.open({
  schema: [ExpenseSchema, UserSchema, AmountSchema],inMemory: true
}).then(realm => {
  realm.write(() => {
    response.map(expense => {
        realm.create("expense", expense);
       setData(data => [...data, expense]); //1) works if I do this
    });
   const objects = realm.objects('expense');
   const values =Object.values(objects);
    //setData([values]); //2) this one doesn't work, nor any of the following attempts
//setData(data => [...data, values]);
  //  setData([values]);
    //setData(objects);
 //setData([objects] 
  });
});
};
```

The 2nd setData call is the one I am trying to get work, but the format of the object array when making the Realm query and isn't being recognized by the flatlist as a data source and throw the following error when trying to render:

```
TypeError: undefined is undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.amount.currency')
```

Here is what response, which comes in a format that works for the flatList data source, looks like:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "amount": Object {
      "currency": "EUR",
      "value": "1854.99",
    },
    "category": "",
    "comment": "",
    "date": "2018-09-10T02:11:29.184Z",
    "id": "5b996064dfd5b783915112f5",
    "index": 0,
    "merchant": "McD",
    "receipts": Array [],
    "user": Object {
      "email": "aaa@ggg.com",
      "first": "Ombly",
      "last": "Lee",
    },
  },
  Object {
    "amount": Object {
      "currency": "GBP",
      "value": "3222.88",
    },
    "category": "",
    "comment": "",
    "date": "2018-08-13T07:11:01.680Z",
    "id": "5b99606474ab17b7820b3922",
    "index": 1,
    "merchant": "BK",
    "receipts": Array [],
    "user": Object {
      "email": "gler@spoto.com",
      "first": "Gler",
      "last": "Spot",
    },
  }, etc....
```

and here is what it looks like when I request it from local RealmDB after storing it:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "0": Object {  <---- seems this extra line is causing the issues. 
      "amount": Object {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "value": "1854.99",
      },
      "date": 2018-09-10T02:11:29.184Z,
      "id": "5b996064dfd5b783915112f5",
      "merchant": "McD",
      "receipt": null,
      "user": Object {
        "email": "aaa@ggg.com",
        "first": "Ombly",
        "last": "Lee",
      },
    },
    "1": Object {
      "amount": Object {
        "currency": "GBP",
        "value": "3222.88",
      },
      "date": 2018-08-13T07:11:01.680Z,
      "id": "5b99606474ab17b7820b3922",
      "merchant": "BK",
      "receipt": null,
      "user": Object {
        "email": "gler@spoto.com",
        "first": "Gler",
        "last": "Spot",
      },
    }, etc....
```

Essentially I need to retrieve the data from Realm in a way that I can use as a flatlist data source.

Thank you so much in advance.

**Edit**
Here is how the API response looks:

```
{
"expenses": [
    {
        "id": "5b996064dfd5b783915112f5",
        "amount": {
            "value": "1854.99",
            "currency": "EUR"
        },
        "date": "2018-09-10T02:11:29.184Z",
        "merchant": "McD",
        "receipts": [],
        "comment": "",
        "category": "",
        "user": {
            "first": "Ombly",
            "last": "Lee",
            "email": "aaa@ggg.com"
        },
        "index": 0
    },
    {
        "id": "5b99606474ab17b7820b3922",
        "amount": {
            "value": "3222.88",
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "date": "2018-08-13T07:11:01.680Z",
        "merchant": "BK",
        "receipts": [],
        "comment": "",
        "category": "",
        "user": {
            "first": "Gler",
            "last": "Spot",
            "email": "gler@spoto.com"
        },
        "index": 1
    }, etc....
 ]
```

**My FlatList**

```
 return (
<View>
  <ScrollView>
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <ExpenseCard
          date={item.date}
          category={item.category}
          amount={item.amount.currency + item.amount.value}
          merchant={item.merchant}
          user={
            item.user.first + " " + item.user.last + "\n" + item.user.email
          }
        />
      )}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    />
  </ScrollView>
</View>
  );
}
```

Comment: For this Extra `{}` bracket you have to Filter or Set Data on your server before sending it in this API.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Can you give an example of Filter? Also, I don't have ability to modify the server.

Comment: Ask Your Backend Developer to modify it. And Also Share actual dala from your `console.log()`

Comment: These data structure snippets are from console.log. also, the API response structure is completely standard as far as responses go - I've added it to the botton to give an example.

Comment: please add your `Flatlist`.

Comment: I've added the flatlist.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<FlatList 
     data={this.state.YourApiData.expenses} //You need to access expenses key.
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
     renderItem={({item,index}) =>
           <View key={index}>
              <View >
                <Text>ID: {item.id}</Text>
                <Text>Amount and Currency: {item.amount.value} - {item.amount.currency}</Text>
                <Text>Date: {item.date}</Text>
               </View>
            </View>
    />
```